# nothing happens when i click on burpsuite / parrot 4.11.1

Tags: parrot-os

I have a very simple problem, but one that I haven't been able to find an answer for. I was looking to work on a web app CTF so one of the tools I used was burpsuite. I'm on a fresh install of ParrotOs so of course I had to set up the burp proxy and download the CA certificate. I did all that then when I went to launch burpsuite nothing happened. It was working good for about 5 minutes. Then I closed it, tried opening it and nothing. Wondering if anyone has had this problem and if they happened to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
your whole parrot will be updated & upgraded including burpsuite and it will run without any problem if any appears then `run burpsuite in a terminal` it will shows you the log.

Comment: thank you this helped and I resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, that is because of the Java languages. Please type in your terminal:

```
apt get list java
```

or

```
which java
```

or

```
whereis java
```

OR

```
java --version
```